# Run C++ analysis with VS solution file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sonarqube

I want to analyse a more complex C++-Project with SonarQube (v4.4) and the Cxx-Plugin v0.9.1 (Community C++).
It includes many sub-projects in different directories.
I got a VS2005 solution file (*.sln) which referes to the relevent *.vcproj files or alternativ mwc + mpc files.

I was now wondering, what the best way to do this analysis is.

Sure, I could write a sonar-project.properties file manually with all directories.

But isn't there a possibilty to run the analysis using the given workspace / project files I got? I could think of e.g. Sonar-Runner readout information from that files to create modules with given direcotry (and maybe automatically includes the defined addionaly includes).

I found Plug-Ins like "Analysis Bootstrapper for Visual Studio Projects Plugin" or the .Net-Plug-In, but obviously they don't support vcproj files.

Thanks for any help and best regards

Comment: This is not directly your question, but there is a build-wrapper tool coming with the SonarSource C++ commercial plugin: http://www.sonarqube.org/with-great-power-comes-great-configuration/

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio comes with C++ static code analysis, but for 2005/2008 you need the team edition. 2010/2012 it is available in the premium edition. It is now available in the 2013 professional edition.

Otherwise I would look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97454/c-static-code-analysis-tool-on-windows)